# Creating a maxtric with strings and floats in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want a matrix with the first row being the title (magnetic fields for every different way of approximation I used) and the results for every datasheet I used.

I'm trying to get this as a result (example):

```
FieldB =  
B1   B2   B3  
1.0  2.0  3.0  
1.1  2.7  2.3  
...  
...  
...  
0.7  2.4  5.8
```

Right now, I'm programming it like this

```
B1(1,1)= 'Field 1';  
B2(1,1)= 'Field 2';  
B3(1,1)= 'Field 3';  
for i=1:n  
    B1(i+1,1)=polyn(1)*Zsplit1(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;  
    B2(i+1,1)=polyn(1)*Zsplit2(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;  
    B3(i+1,1)=polyn(1)*Zsplit3(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;  
end  
FieldB = [B1 B2 B3]
```

And the error given is :

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in 3field (line 32)
B1(1,1)= 'Field 1';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't store strings in an array in Matlab.  Try using a cell array.  You can do that here just by changing `[]` to `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

In matlab the standard matrix cannot have both numbers and strings in it. So, you will need to use another data type to achieve your goal.

In your case, a struct ([see here](http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/dataStructures.html#59)) would be the most natural choice:

```
B(1).name = 'Field 1';
B(2).name = 'Field 2';
B(3).name = 'Field 3';

for i=1:n  
    B(1).data = polyn(1)*Zsplit1(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
    B(2).data = polyn(1)*Zsplit2(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
    B(3).data = polyn(1)*Zsplit3(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
end
```

You could also use a [cell array](http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/dataStructures.html#13)

```
B{1,1} = 'Field 1';
B{1,2} = 'Field 2';
B{1,3} = 'Field 3';
...
for i=1:n  
    B{2,1} = polyn(1)*Zsplit1(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
    B{2,2} = polyn(1)*Zsplit2(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
    B{2,3} = polyn(1)*Zsplit3(i)/10^9+polyn(2)*10^-3;
end
```